# Group by date for irregular time data list and get average for date?

Tags: c#

model

```
public class MeterReadingsBccChartData
{
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> DateAndValue { get; set; }

    public MeterReadingsBccChartData(List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> dateAndValue, string typeName, string unit, string BranchName)
    {
        this.DateAndValue = dateAndValue;
        this.TypeName = typeName;
        this.Unit = unit;
        this.BranchName = BranchName;
    }
}
```

model-to-chartSeries method

```
public static List<Series> GetBccChartData(IEnumerable<MeterReadingsBccChartData> meterReadings)
{
    List<Series> series = new List<Series>();
    foreach (var item in meterReadings)
    {
        int lenght = item.DateAndValue.Count();
        object[,] data = new object[lenght, 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        {
            data[i, 0] = item.DateAndValue[i].Item1;
            data[i, 1] = item.DateAndValue[i].Item2;
        }
        Series localSeries = new Series { Name = item.BranchName + " " + item.TypeName + " " + item.Unit, Data = new Data(data), Type = ChartTypes.Column };
        series.Add(localSeries);
    }

    return series;
}
```

**above code description**

I read data from db. Data type is `MeterReadingsBccChartData`. Then I convert it to `Series` data type and I store this series a list. I want to add an average series to this list. But there may be no data for same date. For example my data looks following:

```
Series 1 : { { date : 01.01.2013, value : 5 }, { date : 02.01.2013, value : 10 } }
Series 2 : { { date : 01.01.2013, value : 11 }, { date : 03.01.2013, value : 3 } }
```

I want to calculate average of these series I want some thing like this:

```
Series AVG : { { date : 01.01.2013, value : 8 }, { date : 02.01.2013, value : 10 } { date : 03.01.2013, value : 3 } }
```

I can do this with second db fetching. I get average values between dates. So I get data from db two times.

Is there any way to calculate avg of this series in above method? Any tips?

I hope I can explain...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I cant explain my problem. I find a solution. I dont know this is the best, but I fetch data from db one time.

```
public static List<Series> GetBccChartData(IEnumerable<MeterReadingsBccChartData> meterReadings)
{
    List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> allData = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
    List<Series> series = new List<Series>();
    foreach (var item in meterReadings)
    {
        int lenght = item.DateAndValue.Count();
        object[,] data = new object[lenght, 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        {
            allData.Add(item.DateAndValue[i]);
            data[i, 0] = item.DateAndValue[i].Item1;
            data[i, 1] = item.DateAndValue[i].Item2;
        }
        Series localSeries = new Series { Name = item.BranchName + " " + item.TypeName + " " + item.Unit, Data = new Data(data), Type = ChartTypes.Column };
        series.Add(localSeries);
    }

    // ortalama serisi hesaplanıyor.
    List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> averageData = allData.GroupBy(x => x.Item1).Select(x => Tuple.Create<DateTime, double>(x.Key, x.Average(item => item.Item2))).ToList();
    int avgDataLenght = averageData.Count();
    object[,] dataAvg = new object[avgDataLenght, 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < avgDataLenght; i++)
    {
        dataAvg[i, 0] = averageData[i].Item1;
        dataAvg[i, 1] = averageData[i].Item2;
    }
    Series avgSeries = new Series { Name = "Genel Toplam", Data = new Data(dataAvg), Type = ChartTypes.Line };
    series.Add(avgSeries);

    return series;
}
```